# document.ready page reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm starting my adventure with js and jQuery and I can't understand why my function `pokaz_czas()` is not executed when I reload the page.

I use a script in a php file (wpis.php), which I'm including in another php file (index.php?page=wpis).  I want my function to execute when I reload the page (index.php?...)

Javascript Code:

```
  function zero(element) 
{ //1
if (element < 10) return element = "0" + element;
return element;
}
function pokaz_czas() 
{
    var czas = new Date();
    var data = czas.getFullYear()+"-"+zero((czas.getMonth()+1))+"-"+zero(czas.getDate());
    var time = zero(czas.getHours())+":"+zero(czas.getMinutes());

    $('#data').val(data);
    $('#time').val(time);

}
$(document).ready(pokaz_czas());

$(document).ready
(
function()
{       
    $('#data').change
        (
            function()
            {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
        );
}
);
```

By the way, if I do...

```
 ...
 var time = zero(czas.getHours())+":"+zero(czas.getMinutes());

    $('#data').val(data);
    $('#time').val(time);
    setTimeout("pokaz_czas()",1000)
}
```

...then the function is executing (but it does so every second, and I want to execute it only once).

Sorry for my English, it' s my first post here ;)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this: `$(document).ready(pokaz_czas);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , definitely try this way:

```
$(document).ready(pokaz_czas);
```

It means you don't want to fire `pokaz_czas` immediately , only when your `DOM` is ready

Comment: sorry didnt knew that when i call function i dont need the '()' thing. TY very much!!, it works now:D I should sign up here faster;)

Comment: @Joe no , it works in jsfiddle only because under "Frameworks & Extensions" it is signed as "onLoad"